# Changing Date Value to Week Day Name Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make the below formulae into **VBA syntax**.  **My objective** is that when a user inputs a **Date Value Starting from Cell (“A4”)**   the adjacent cell starting from **cell (“F4”)** will return the **Day Name**.  However if there is no Date value in cell (“A4”) to last row the corresponding adjacent cell in column F should not have a value.

The Syntax I have an excel formulae is

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A4),"dddd")
```

As a VBA recorder all I am getting is the below:

```
Sub Day_Names()
    Range("F4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(WEEKDAY(RC[-5]),""dddd"")"
    Range("F4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F4:F29"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("F4:F29").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: so the problem at the moment is actually that if a4 or a5 a6 and so on has no value then the corresponding F cell should be blank right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However if there is no Date value in cell (“A4”) to last row the corresponding adjacent cell in column F should not have a value.

The formula that you need in `F4` is `=IF(A4="","",TEXT(WEEKDAY(A4),"dddd"))`

You don't need to autofill. you can enter the formula in one go to the entire range. See this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set Rng = ws.Range("F4:F29")

    Rng.Formula = "=IF(A4="""","""",TEXT(WEEKDAY(A4),""dddd""))"
End Sub
```

[image]